# Regex for words ending in .com or .co.au etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex but cannot get the right one - 
 
The regex should be able to check a string where the 1st part before a . (dot) is any group of letters (case insensitive) or numbers. After the dot there is either .com or .co.xy where x and y are any 2 letters (case insensitive). I tried this but it didn't work: 
`/^(?!.*\.com+.co.**$).*$/` 
Some examples which would qualify: 
 
`ghikl.com` 
`jk.com` 
`k5343.com` 
`lop.co.vb` 
`kkkkpol.com` 
`09k.co.lp`

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(com|co\.[a-zA-Z]{2})$`

Comment: tld are not necessarily two characters but could be of any length.

Comment: Ok, one more thing - the above regex works only if I test it against an exact url. What if the url exists somewhere inside a full paragraph?